# Oracle , trigger before update

Tags: oracle

Could you please help me ?
I need to create the trigger that compare two dates and one number column and depending from them insert into character column words.
I have idea how it should looks but in my script something wrong.
This is my example
Thank you.

```
create trigger booking_trigger
before insert on booking
for each row
 WHEN (new.booking_id IS NULL)
   begin
     if sys_date > paid_date and ammount>0  =:new.'Paid' from dual;
     elsif sys_date > paid_date and ammount=0  =:new.'Not paid' from dual;
     elsif sys_date < paid_date and ammount=0 =:new.'Waiting';
    else :=new.'Broken'
   end if;
end
/
```

Comment: Your code has some issues; please post the table structure and the logic you need to implement to help people helping you. Also, some sample data with desired behaviour would be useful to clarify the question and help people to build an example and test code before posting

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with [IF THEN ELSIF](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS391). Clearly the keyword `then` is missing.

Which column do you wish to update? Let's say it is `a_column`. In such case you set its value to `'Paid'` as follows:

```
:new.a_column := 'Paid';
```

You can read more about triggers [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS020)